How do I block a Personal account in corporate Teams?
I have a personal account using my work email address I created many years ago, but then work signed up to corporate Office 365, so I now have both accounts on the same email address.
However, a recent update to Teams now logs me into both accounts. I can sign out of the personal account, but an icon hangs around, and on PC restart it once again auto-logs me in.
Is there an easy way to stop the personal side of Teams completely?
